# Embed MS Access Database in C# WinForm app

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, embedded-resource

I have a C# winform application that accesses data from an MS Access database. This means my applications requires at least 2 files, the .exe file and the .accdb file. Is it possible to include the database in the .exe file, so my solution consists of a single file (the same way you would include an image in the project resources)? If it is possible, are they any major reasons why it shouldn't be done and how would you access the data from code? The project is a only a little one for personal use so if performance is hit it doesn't matter too much.

thanks in advance

Comment: I'll assume you mean you want a single EXE setup file, as opposed to your final app being a single EXE within which the MDB is embedded. The latter is too absurd to be contemplated, and is completely impossible in any case (probably with any database engine at all).

Answer (score 4):

It *can* be done. Simply add it to your project as you would add any other file (right click project -> Add -> Existing Item), then cancel all the dialogs that will popup offering you to handle it for you, then right click your database from your project explorer, go to properties and select `Build Action`: `Embedded Resource`.

Then use the method below to dump your database into a temporary file, which you can create by calling `Path.GetTempFileName`.

```
internal void CreateBlankDatabase(string destFile)
{
    using (Stream source = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.MyEmbeddedDatabase))
    using (Stream target = File.Open(destFile, FileMode.Truncate))
    {
        source.CopyTo(target);
    }
}
```

(Note that `MyEmbeddedDatabase` would be your embedded database name). Then use your temporary file name in your connection string. Make sure you delete your temporary file after you're done. Also, as other said, you won't be able to modify and save any data.

Comment: @nawfal Why not? Doesn't it show how to embed a database in a project like you would embed a picture?

Comment: what is the point in merely embedding a database like resource and dumping it if user cant edit and save it, in the above question. The whole purpose of a database is to save data. I mean your answer only partly answers it, but with no use since you can only dump, not modify

Comment: @nawfal: Well we don't know for sure if he wants to modify his data (he doesn't say it in the question). Is not the whole purpose of a database to save data but just half of it, the other half being to read data. I'm sure there are situations on which you don't need to modify existing data in a database. If you want to also save data then no, it cannot be embedded as others already said.

Comment: its understood by the term database, databases are to save our own data and then read. What's the purpose in deploying a database only to read? He can have faster ways by writing them in the code itself. Database associates with custom data AFAIK

Comment: Well I actually use this very method to embed a blank Access database so I can then dump it out, modify it at runtime and then save it as a file (since my app includes a light database editor which let you create Access databases, so this is how you "create" a blank database). He could, for instance, have purchased a pre-made database of zip codes and their corresponding states that he doesn't need to edit unless he decides to purchase an updated database next year, etc.

Comment: haha I see that. But I wouldn't say that was intended in the question by the OP. By the vagueness of the post, it can only be for ordinary DB transactions.. He would have been specific if reading data has been the requirement. Or who knows, ya you have a point..

Answer (score 2):

No it shouldn't be done. How would you send someone and update to the .exe file without them losing their data? Keep it separate.

You need to have a way to manage how your applications installs and the file location in your connection string(s). There could be a \Data subfolder in your app folder with the .accdb file(s) in it.

Comment: thanks for such a swift response. while i agree with everything you've said, this application will only ever be used by me. i accept that it shouldn't be done, i'm just wondering if it's possible

Comment: It couldn't possibly be done, because Jet/ACE has to update the file, so you can't embed it in the EXE itself. The suggestion is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't achieve what you want with an access database as an embedded resource, but you effectively get the same result by wrapping all your files in another executable app.

When you run the wrapper application, it extracts the "main" C# app, database file, and an updater app (more on this below) to the temporary files folder and runs the main app.

When the main app is closed, it runs the updater app, passing in the paths to the database file and original wrapper application. The updater app updates the wrapper application file with the changed database file. It then finally deletes the database main app and database file from the temp folder. Unfortunately, the updater app can't delete itself, but you could work around that by adding a command to the runonce section of the registry to delete the updater app on the next reboot.

---

Instead of figuring out how to extract and insert embedded resources, consider having the wrapper application as a compressed, self-extracting executable (like a self-extracting zip or rar file). Here's a [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ReduceDotNetSize.aspx) that describes how to turn a .Net app into a compressed, self extracting exe.

Answer (score -2):

Access requires to be able to read and write to the file. The OS will lock the exe when it is run so that it can't be changed while in use. This along will cause it to not work, not to mention that Access simple wouldn't be able to read the exe as it is expecting a different file format.